# Selecting from table in different controller in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In my Users controller I'm trying to display a given users's posts in their profile. How can I accomplish this? Basically, I'm in the Users controller trying to access the Posts table

These are my Tables

```
//Posts
id | body | user_id

//Users
user_id | username
```

This is my profile function of my users

```
  UsersController.php

  public function profile($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {  //if the user doesn't exist while on view.ctp, throw error message
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    $conditions = array('Posts.user_id' => $id);
    $this->set('posts', $this->User->Posts->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions))); 
}


/Posts/profile.ctp     

<table>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

    <tr><td><?php echo $post['Post']['body'];?>
    <br>

    <!--display who created the post -->
    <?php echo $post['Post']['username']; ?>
    <?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I'm getting several "undefined index errors" in reference to each line of profle.ctp

```
Undefined index: Post [APP/View/Users/profile.ctp, line 11]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UsersController` on your `profile` action, you can use the `User` model to access associated information.

Example:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function profile($id = null) {
        $this->User->recursive = 2;
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }
}
```

In your `User` and `Post` model, you should have the correct associations setup:

`User` model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Post');
}
```

`Post` model:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

You will see now that in your view, on the `$user` variable, you have all the user data for the specified profile id, along with associated posts for that user.

[This page in the CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) has some great helpful tips in reading your data from models.